# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register

Tags: meteor

I just installed the meteor framework (www.meteor.com) and I did what the QuickStart Says:

Once you’ve installed Meteor, create a project:

```
meteor create myapp
```

Run it locally:

1. `cd my app`
2. `meteor npm install`
3. `meteor`

## Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/

However I am getting this error:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
  Referenced from: /Users/alexandremagnobezerramiranda/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
  Referenced from: /Users/alexandremagnobezerramiranda/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

So, I would like to know how do I solve this problem? Any Thoughts?

Comment: Please try run this command 'meteor npm rebuild'

Comment: I did it right now but I am getting the same error though